# Return value from nested promise with Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, mocha.js

In my test code I wish to achieve the following:

```
it('Updates label text', function(done) {
   page.testLabelText();
   assert.equal(page.testLabelText().pageLabel, page.testLabelText().iFrameLabel);
   done();
});
```

In my page object, here is `testLabelText();`:

```
page.testLabelText = function () {
    var pageLabel = function () {
        return driver.findElement(By.css('#element')).getText().then(function(text) {
            return text;
        });
    };
    var iFrameLabel = function () {
        return driver.findElement(By.css('#element')).getText().then(function(text) {
            return text;
        });
    };
    return {
        pageLabel: pageLabel(),
        iFrameLabel: iFrameLabel()
    };
};
```

But this returns 'Undefined' when printed to the console...I'm a newbie at javascript so though I've managed this in regular javascript, everything I've tried has failed with selenium WebdriverJS promises...

Comment: How exactly do your `pageLabel` and `iFrameLabel` functions differ? Is `'#element'` a placeholder?

Comment: pagelabel refers to the label on the main page, which updates from user input. Afer this the iframe is supposed to update  with its own label that should reflect what's on the main page.  #element was just an example, but is actually the css selector for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use an assertion library that could resolve promises in the tests, as this would be impossible using regular async asserts. In this case I used [Chai as Promised.](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/)

Requiring the following:

```
chai = require('chai'),
chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised"),
should = chai.should();
```

and including `chai.use(chaiAsPromised);` in mocha's `before` hook, I could then write

```
it('Updates label text', function() {
  var label = FormsPage.testLabelText();
  label.labelHeading.should.eventually.contain(label.userInput);
});
```

I found a blog post on this [here](http://marmelab.com/blog/2016/04/19/e2e-testing-with-node-and-es6.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your `assert.equal()` is comparing two distinct promise objects so that will never be true.  To understand why, here's the step by step.  What you need to do is to get the values out of both the promises after they are resolved and then compare the values.

`page.testLabelText();` by itself just returns an object so calling it by itself with no assignment of the return value or referencing the return value does nothing.

`page.testLabelText().pageLabel` by itself is a promise.

`page.testLabelText().iFrameLabel` by itself is a promise.

And, they are different promise objects so your `assert.equal()` will not be true.

If you wanted to compare the two values from the promises, you'd have to do something like this:

```
var obj = page.testLabelText();
Promise.all(obj.pageLabel, obj.iFrameLabel).then(function(results) {
    assert.equal(results[0], results[1]);
    done();
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `pageLabel` and `iFrameLabel` are Promises, not functions.

Comment: @gyre - You were right.  I corrected that part.  I missed the `()` in the returned object.  I find this code really confusing to read with so many names that are very similar.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the explanation, the code has similar names because the app updates a label on the main page and its equivalent in the iFrame (its a proprietary app can't show unfortunately).

The issue with your solution is that I need to follow best practices and not  have any assertions in the page objects, but also not have any "programming" in the test cases..which is why my only solution so far was to try to run `testLabelText()` and make it return the inner text of the required elements, and assert that they match from within the test case...I find this super tricky.

Comment: @Rup - That's not an obtainable requirement.  It takes extra code to get data from two separate promises and compare that data so you have an unrealistic goal.